# Jar file made by netbeans for concole app, gives "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, console, noclassdeffounderror

In short my problem is that I made a console app project in netbeans which run perfectly in netbeans.

I built a jar file from this project, and the console running gives....

---

```
C:\blabla>java -jar mypath_to_jar\project.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
        at project_pkg.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

---

I extracted the jar and the manifest was:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.7
Created-By: 1.8.0_161-b12 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: my_project_pkg.Main

Does someone have a solution on this problem please?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You miss the dependencies in your classpath

Comment: your jar file is missing the dependencies it still had when you were running it in netbeans. search the jars you need and add them to your local classpath

Answer (score 0):

You are using the jar file as self executing, please check you'r command line. you need to include the jar file to your project and use the project's main entry point.

Comment: Hey! I dont understand what i have to do.... in the comand line there is my jar file... What do you mean to "include the jar file to your project and use the project's main entry point"... Any example how to do this? Thanks....